# Making dynamic selections field required

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to define one dynamic selection field as required.

I created a transaction code with a starting variant.

For this variant in the attributes screen assignment, there is no "required field" option on dynamic selections, only "protect field".

Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Completely unclear on what you've already tried and what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: Are you using ABAP Dynpro or standard selection-screens for example? Basicly, you should decide the type of the selection field. You can do it in Process before output in Dynpro, and AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT event section in standard selection-screens.

Comment: You are talking about the selection screen of an abap report? Maybe you are searching for the screen-required attribute, this will set a field as required. Example:

LOOP AT SCREEN.
    CASE screen-name.
      WHEN 'P_PARAM'.
        screen-required = '1'.
ENDLOOP 

You need to place this within the correct entry point which fits to your requirement (e.g. AT SELCTION-SCREEN OUTPUT)

Comment: Will upload screens tomorrow, so I define the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> On variant attributes screen assignment there is not required field
>   option on dynamic selections

There **is** `Required` attribute in screen variant and it is perfectly usable for making regular field mandatory, and [in dynamic selections too](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/07/24/dynamic-date-selection-in-variants/).

[image]

If you lack it, check your release or maybe your installation is corrupted. I don't believe it is tcode-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the [Dynamic Selections](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-us/index.htm?file=abenfree_selections.htm), then you can only protect the fields. Example with demo program `DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT` (which is based on the `F1S` Logical Database):

[image: Dynamic selections in DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT]

[image: Program variant for dynamic selections in DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT]

You can only protect those fields against input, and all other attributes are deactivated (they are not implemented as you can see in subroutine `MODIFY_SCREEN` of program `SAPLSSEL`).

The only possible workaround to simulate a mandatory field is to implement ABAP code after the user has entered selections (or not). For instance, in the program `DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT`, you may add this ABAP code which checks that the screen field *"Connection Number"* contains a value when the user executes the program:

```
TABLES sscrfields.
AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  DATA dynsel TYPE rsds_trange.
  CALL FUNCTION 'RS_REFRESH_FROM_DYNAMICAL_SEL'
    EXPORTING
      curr_report        = sy-repid
      mode_write_or_move = 'W'
    IMPORTING
      p_trange           = dynsel
    EXCEPTIONS
      not_found          = 1
      wrong_type         = 2.
  DATA(connid) = VALUE spfli-connid(
    dynsel[ tablename = 'SPFLI'
        ]-frange_t[ fieldname = 'CONNID'
            ]-selopt_t[ 1 ]-low OPTIONAL ).
  IF sscrfields-ucomm = 'ONLI' AND connid IS INITIAL.
    MESSAGE 'Flight Connection number is required' TYPE 'E'.
  ENDIF.
```

NB: Tested with ABAP 7.52. Dynamic Selections can be implemented implicitly via Logical Databases (which are obsolete since ABAP 7.02 or 7.31) or explicitly by calling the function modules `FREE_SELECTIONS_INIT` and `FREE_SELECTIONS_DIALOG`.